# Comparing two .csv files and write into 3rd file

Tags: awk, csv, macos, join

On my Mac I have two files:

`file1.csv` (about 4000 rows)

```
1234,yxds
4352,fsfk
8765,fdgj
7874,hffe
9038,fjro
8297,fhjs
```

and `file2.csv` (about 50 rows)

```
1234,"number","date","OS"
4352,"number","date","OS"
8765,"number","date","OS"
8297,"number","date","OS"
```

file 3 should look like this:

```
1234,yxds
4352,fsfk
8765,fdgj
8297,fhjs
```

So I only want the entries that exist in `file2.csv` but with column 2 of `file1.csv`

Essentially I want to write a script compares `file1.csv` to a different `file3.csv`

So far I tried `join` and `awk` but with no success. This is what i tried so far :

```
join -t, -12 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 file1.csv file2.csv > file 3.csv
```

and

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if ($1 in a && a[$1] != $2)print;}' FS="|" file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

Comment: just updated the post, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Does the output have to be in the same order as the input files? And if so, which one?

Comment: Are both the file de-limited by `|`?

Comment: the order doesn't matter, just that every entry in file2.csv matching an entry in file1.csv gets column 2 of file1.csv written in file3.csv

Comment: I edited a whole bunch of minor typos in your question, but are your commands really correct? i.e. `> file 3.csv` isn't going to work.

Comment: @Inian they are separated by ","

Comment: just clarified in a comment below that i'm on macOS, not linux. Sorry i didn't clarify that in the original post!

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` on sorted files:

```
join -o 1.1,1.2 <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) > file3.csv
```

- `-o 1.1,1.2` means output `file1.field1` and `file1.field2`

Output:

```
1234 yxds
4352 fsfk
8297 fhjs
8765 fdgj
```

Comment: It keeps giving me an error: syntax error near unexpected token `('
It doesn't seem to get the included sort command. I'm working in terminal on mac, not linux, if that helps

Comment: yes it matters. `<(...)` is `bash` syntax, I put that because you added `bash` as a tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm new to the forum

Comment: Even if i sort the files before, the output file ends up being empty

Comment: Note that `<(...)` is ksh syntax (copied decades later by zsh and bash).

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 files f1 and f2 with the required content and run the following (It will work if you want to include `8297` in the output)

```
sort -k1 f1 > ff1
sort -k1 f2 > ff2
join ff1 ff2 | cut -d ' ' -f1 > t1.txt
join ff1 ff2 | cut -d ' ' -f2 > t2.txt
paste t1.txt t2.txt > finaloutput.out
rm f1 f2 ff1 ff2
```

finaloutput.out will contain the required output

Comment: I wonder a bit why you don't use `cut -f1,2` instead of using 2x`cut`+ `paste`.

Comment: I didn't know that multiple columns could be extracted this way..
Thanks @pLumo

Comment: unfortunately all the files end up being empty

Comment: @Sotey edit the last line to this one
`rm  ff1 ff2`

Comment: no difference sadly

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

```
mlr --nidx join -j 1 --lp 2 -f input_01.csv then unsparsify then cut -f 1,22 input_02.csv
```

You will have

```
1234 yxds
4352 fsfk
8765 fdgj
8297 fhjs
```

Comment: Thanks!! i would prefer to do it without a 3rd party application, since I also want to share it with some of my users without them having to install something first

Comment: @Sotey I do not know what kind of users you have: install Miller is very easy and give you a tool with a lot of great features. I'm adding this comment because it seems that you haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your search terms (first column of file2.csv) as search pattern file to grep:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' file2.csv | grep -f - file1.csv 

1234 yxds
4352 fsfk
8765 fdgj
8297 fhjs
```